# Android second activity is ignoring xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-4.4-kitkat

In my second activity I have a textview that is not responding to the changes in the xml file, I'm trying to change the text size and alignment but nothing I do works, I can only guess that it because in the java file for the activity I have a .setText method changing the text of the textView and that's causing the program to ignore the xml file, my question is how to I now change the text size?

Java code:

```
package com.powermedia.rps;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
/**
* Created by Joshua on 2/17/2015.
*/
public class ResultActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements      View.OnClickListener
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Button playAgainBtn;
    TextView resulttv;
    String userChoice = "";
    String AndroidChoice = "";
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);
    playAgainBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PlayAgain);
    playAgainBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    resulttv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    userChoice = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("userChoice");
    AndroidChoice = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("AndroidChoice");
    resulttv.setText("User chose " + userChoice + ", Android chose " +   AndroidChoice +
    "\n" + getWinner(AndroidChoice, userChoice) + " won!");
}
```

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#ffd3d3d3"
android:id="@+id/test">

<Space
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/space3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play Again"
    android:id="@+id/PlayAgain"
    android:layout_below="@+id/space3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ff959595" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Tell who won or tie"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Comment: Noting is being ignored. The xml file loads then you change the text in Java but you aren't changing the text size or anything else. Make sure that your `TextView` has the correct attributes you want in the GUI before running the app. You may want to explain a little better too because the question/problem isn't exactly clear.

Comment: you should move the declarations of the Button and Textview out of `onCreate()` to private member variables of the class. not sure what happens when `onCreate()` is finished and you, say, click the Button

Comment: @DavidM Why? If they aren't used anywhere else then that's exactly where they should go.

Comment: @codeMagic - he declares an onClickListener on the button. the button is out of scope after the `onCreate()`. just seems like a mistake to me.

Comment: So to be clear the java .setText is overriding the text attributes defined in the textView xml, so how to I change font size and alignment (to center horizontal) in java then

Comment: @DavidM possibly but there's really no way to know where it needs to be declared without seeing the whole class. The `onClick()` will have a reference to the `Button` so, as far as the `Button` is concerned, that isn't an issue. @JimRhodes, good catch

Comment: @JoshuaPowers it *isn't* overriding anything besides the text. Again, did you check in the graphical editor of your IDE before running to see if it shows how you expect?

Comment: @codeMagic I am using the graphical editor and it shows the changes I want but when I run the program and run it on an actual device the text is what it was before the changes, it seems to be ignoring the xml

Comment: Also changing dp to sp had no effect.

Comment: Before what changes? Once you run the app, you can't change what is in the xml file. The text is going to change to whatever `String` is in `setText()`

Comment: @codeMagic I am trying to change the size and alignment of the text, I had it originally at 20dp size wise and left alignment but now I want to change it, to something else, (still trying to decide what i want to change it to)

Comment: @JimRhodes the name of the XML file is result.xml and that's the entirety of the xml in the file, there is no second textSize line

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuilding. Sounds like the changes aren't being compiled

Comment: That didn't work, I even tried restarting the app, it's weird I am certain it was working fine yesterday

Comment: I'm using android studio, by the way

Comment: It's ignoring the xml file completely, why would it do this, even if I add or take away elements from the layout, I recompile the app be nothing has changed in the layout of the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
android:textSize="20dp"
```

to:

```
android:textSize="20sp"
```